# "There was an error while performing this operation"

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a website in IIS for which I cannot open any of the settings like Authentication, Handler Mappings, Authorization Rules etc. It just shows the error message "There was an error while performing this operation", with no more details and points to web.config.

Browsing the website results in a 500.19 error.

I tried adding `iis_iusrs` to the website folder and web.config, changing the app pool identity giving access to same on web.config/website folder security settings, verified target framework, iisreset/app pool recycles to no avail.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

It turned out the website was using URL rewrite module which i was missing.

Downloaded web platform installer from MS and installed URL rewrite module.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Wish IIS errors were more informative than just "There was an error..."

Comment: The URL Rewrite module can be the cause of a number of misleading error messages and countless hours wasted...

Comment: The way to trouble shoot is remove the rewrite section in web.config.  If this solves the problem you need the rewrite module.

Comment: Thank You! I installed it from here https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite as of March 2022

Comment: Absolute lifesaver. Yet another useless error message. Thank you very much for taking the time to post this answer.

Answer (score 38):

I am running IIS 8.5 and I deployed my first Asp.Net Core 2.0 (Razor pages) site to the IIS Server (on Windows Server 2012 R2) that was running several Asp.Net Framework/Classic websites.  This worked for me:

Install the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle

Comment: the hosting bundle is now part of .NET Core 2.1 SDk 
 https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Comment: This solved it for me too! I already had URL Rewrite installed, and existing sites run on .Net Framework. Today I'm adding a new website that runs on .Net Core, and installing the .Net Core Hosting Bundle fixed it for me. Got it from here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Comment: This was the problem that I had, but I needed the [.NET Core 6](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.6-windows-hosting-bundle-installer) bundle.

Answer (score 27):

> It turned out the website was using URL rewrite module which i was missing.

This wasn't my problem and it was. I already had URL Rewriter installed, but after a Windows 10 upgrade IIS wasn't aware of it. A simple repair on Control Panel => Programs and Features => IIS URL Rewrite Module 2 and it was working again.

Comment: you saved my day! I had same issue and resolved in exactly same way as you suggested and all works again now. in our case we upgraded server from windows 2012 to windows 2016.

Comment: legend. I was re-installing a trashed server and every time I created a site for one of the sites to be restored I would see this error. I'd forgotten about the re-write rules in the web.config!

Comment: I was fighting with that to run NAV Web Client.
I reinstalled a lot of things here lol
Bro, it also saved my life.
Only repairing Rewrite Module worked, thins :)

Comment: I had the same issue, reinstallation of rewrite module was not useful for me, but repairing worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

My issue was that I installed the .NET Core Hosting Bundle before I installed IIS.  Re-running the Hosting Bundle installer with Repar fixed it for me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle

> If the Hosting Bundle is installed before IIS, the bundle installation
>   must be repaired. Run the Hosting Bundle installer again after
>   installing IIS.

Comment: I didn't even need to find the installer to run it.  I just went into Control Panel -> Programs and Features and then right-clicked on the Microsoft .NET Core 3.1.2 - Windows Server Hosting item and selected Change which then brought up the option to Repair.  Right after it repaired, it all worked.

Comment: In my case, I uninstalled all the different versions of .NET Core versions. Again installed the one I wanted to install. After that I am able to open the SSL settings.

Comment: Also as @MDave commented, in another instance, repairing existing .NET Core Hosting Bundle fixed the issue for me.

Comment: The repair also worked for us, we uninstalled all the .net core 2 stuff and broke IIS.

Answer (score 14):

I had this issue as well. Trying to run ASP.Net Core on IIS 10. All I needed to do was this:
[image: Development Time IIS Support]

Screen shot taken from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue lately , the solution for me was installing :
 **ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle.**
You can find it [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2).

Also before installing it , make sure your `wwwroot` security permissions is set to allow both `iis_iusrs` and `iusr` to have Read, Write and Execute permissions.

Answer (score 5):

same here
also IUSR was missing from anonymous authentication credentials.

If the .net core Hosting Bundle is installed before IIS, the bundle installation must be repaired. Run the Hosting Bundle installer again after installing IIS.

Answer (score 4):

I installed .Net core Hosting Bundle from  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2 and it fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the marked solution here, I had the same problem and again it was a missing IIS module, but this time it was the Application Initialization Module that was required, not URLRewrite. installing via the Web Platform Installer or [IIS.net](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization). fixed the problem.

Steps I took to debug this though was to section by section go through my web config removing each section and attempting to load the site and/or let IIS parse the config. When I removed the section pertaining to initialization optimisation this fixed the issue and I immediately remembered that this dependency was added a fair while ago.

Echo the sentiments though that this really needs better error messages!!!

Answer (score 2):

**works 100%  ****check any urls are there inside `<appSetting></appSetting>`, try to comment these unknown urls**

```
 <!-- <add key="ErrorLogWebApi" value="https://websitename.com/api" />-->
```

and also comment `<rewrite></rewrite>` tag completely

now you try

Comment: An empty rewrite tag was causing the error for me when I clicked 'Logging'. Have an upvote.

Comment: This was my issue to. Removed the rewrite tag and it works. Have another upvote

Comment: Similar issue, rewrite rule was populated but URL Rewrite module wasn't installed, causing the error

Answer (score 1):

1. I just double click on the Application that have the error and
2. change the version of the .NET Framework and
3. then change it back to the original version and
4. recycled the App Pools.

**e.g.:**

The application has **.NET Framework v4.0.30319** and I changed it to **.NET Framework v2.0.50727** then the Status was turn into *Stop*, then I double click back and change to **.NET Framework v4** and then right click ***recycle*** and recycled it.

Comment: try using a list to improve your answer and to be clearer

Answer (score 1):

Same error message, but my C:\ had run out of disk space.

Comment: The answer that best represents the M$ experience.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was my mistake.

I just wanted to **make a backup of web.config** file. So I took the fiel from the website and **copied to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\`**.
Nothing else. The file even looks like there is no (xml) formatting error or whatnot.

It's sad the there is no error in event viewer, no good log file, nothing.
After a lot of time googling similar errors I ran Process Monitor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what config files are read. And that's how I found that the backup is used, actually.

After I removed the file, the site started working again.