# can't retrieve web.config while hosting the application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

The exception occurs when clicking on Connection string in IIS Manager

"There was an error while performing this operation 
Details: 
Filename:\?D:\Work\kxbedbooker\web\Kxbnb\web.config
Error:
"

Comment: Please add more information about your issue.

Comment: You need to show your `web.config`.

Comment: Check which version you are using for development and if framework is installed on machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["There was an error while performing this operation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199424/there-was-an-error-while-performing-this-operation)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This see if it work, the issue is may be the framework version.                

  1.Try to open IIs.
  2.Go to the Application pool.
  3.Open the Advanced Settings of Application Pool.
  4.Change the .Net CLR version from 'V4.0' to 'No Managed Code'.

Enable Directory Browser as well in IIS.
```