# IIS Website Authentication Error In Web.config

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, iis-express

I have deployed the websites in IIS under Default Web Site. I need to check the Authentication for the website, so when I click on the Authentication feature after selecting the Website from the left panel. It's popping up an error window.
[IIS Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idmLk.png)

I have validated the suggested config file and everything looks good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net core web api published in IIS after moved to different IIS server pc gives error 500.19 (0x8007000d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034308/asp-net-core-web-api-published-in-iis-after-moved-to-different-iis-server-pc-giv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second answer of the below article solved this problem for me

["There was an error while performing this operation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199424/there-was-an-error-while-performing-this-operation/40178756)